# “a book” vs. “books”. Subtle differences of meaning between singular and plural nouns

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Which is more appropriate for introducing myself?
And what is the difference of meaning?

“I like reading a book.”

“I like reading books.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say "I like reading books" means that you like reading books as a hobby, in your spare time etc.

If you say instead "I like reading a book", it will refer to a particular book now, which you haven't named yet. It'd be a strange sentence to share with people if you don't complement it afterwards with the name of the book (it's a bit like a guessing game: "I like reading a book -- can you guess which one?").

Long story short, you probably want to use only the former, "I like reading *books*". If you like reading a particular book, you'd probably express this differently, like "I'm enjoying [reading] this book" or "I love reading again and again that particular book". Saying "I like reading a book that was written in the 16th century and talks about..." still sounds a bit odd, you'd rather say you're enjoying reading it or you're liking it (period)

Comment: Thank you for giving me a well-organized and excellent answer!

Comment: @Takuto Thank you for your kind compliment!:) But I should add that what Jay said is correct and I hadn't thought of it before. People might say "In my free time, I like to read a book." and this would sound natural. Still, I think the most intuitive option would be to say "In my free time, I like reading books". And saying "I like reading a book" just by itself still doesn't sound natural, certainly not as natural as "I like reading books"

Answer (score 0):

In practice, the two sentences would be understood to mean the same thing.

"I like reading a book" could mean that there is one particular book that you like to read over and over. But unless you followed up by saying what book that is, most listeners would understand you to mean that you like to read books in general. In this case, the singular means that you read one book at a time, not that there is one book that you read and re-read constantly.

Comment: "I like reading a book", just by itself, would be a unusual thing for a native speaker to say. If we meant "I like (or prefer) to read one book at at a time", that is what we would say.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey People often say, "In my free time, I like to read a book." Not meaning the same book every time, but that they will read some book.